# portrait and landscape advice

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have 2 xml file (main.xml) one in layout, one in layout-land. in that xml I have a listView. So when I run my application in landscape mode and after that turn device in portrait mode it is working fine but when I run my application in portrait mode and turn in landscape mode, the data of listView not loading anymore. I don't understand what's problem could I have here. Landscape -> portrait is fine, portraid -> landscape is bad. Is there any idea of this.

loading data here.

```
 public void loadData(final User user) {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    init(user);
                    getUserGroups(user.getSocialAcountByName("way").getSocial_uid(), "way");
                }
            }); 
        }
```

Comment: Where do you load the data (which method)? I think this might be an Activity lifecycle issue. Could you post some code?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but that's not exactly what I meant. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. What I mean is, in which Activity lifecycle method do you load the data (onCreate, onStart, etc.)? If I remember correctly the Activity gets restarted when you change to portrait/landscape.

Comment: That's your problem then. Try loading the data in onStart. Also look at this -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: Or maybe `onResume` would be better, but I can't check that at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your activities' lifecycle. If you just load the data in `onCreate` you're going to lose it everytime the activity restarts (and this might happen anytime). So you probably just need to move the data loading to `onResume` to be safe.